# Recursive Dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core

I have a problem with recursive dependencies (.Net Core 2).
I have the following classes

```
public interface ISettings
{
    string GetValue(string key);
}
public class Settings : ISettings
{
    internal Settings(Dictionary<string,string> values)
    {
        _items = values;
    }
    Dictionary<string, string> _items;
    public string GetValue(string key)
    {
        return _items[key];
    }
}
```

which used for reading settings data from the dictionary.
The next one is

```
public interface ISettingsClient
{
    Dictionary<string, string> GetSettings();
}
public class SettingsClient: ISettingsClient
{
    internal SettingsClient(ILogger logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
    ILogger _logger;

    public Dictionary<string, string> GetSettings()
    {
        _logger.Log("log something");
        //read settings from the service
        return new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "key", "value" } };
    }
}
```

It used for getting settings values from the 3rd party service,
this client used the Logger instance which looks like this

```
public interface ILogger
{
    void Log(string message);
}
public interface IProducer
{
    void Send<T>(T message);
}
public class Logger:ILogger
{
    internal Logger(string producerConnectionString)
    {
        _producer = new Producer(this, producerConnectionString);
    }
    IProducer _producer;

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        _producer.Send(message);
    }
}
public class Producer:IProducer
{
    public Producer(ILogger logger, string connectionString)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    ILogger _logger;

    public void Send<T>(T message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("send message");
    }
}
```

Logger is using Producer instance for sending a message to queue
and connectionString = settings.GetValue("ProducerConnectionstring")

- to initialize the Settings I need to initialize SettingsClient
- to Initialize SettingsClient I need an instance of ILogger
- to initialize ILogger I need to read the "ProducerConnectionString" value from the Settings

Settings and Logger are Singletons

How to resolve recursive dependencies between Logger and Settings by using DI container?
Does it possible at all?

I have a legacy architecture which is working fine without any DI container and it just initializing the instance of Logger, then reading the settings and then set the ProducerConnectionString value via "Initialize" method (and also this method sends messages that were stored in memory, while Producer was not initialized). 
But I would like to use DI container (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection), and I don't understand how it can be implemented. Seems to me it is not possible and I have to remove somehow the Logger instance from the SettingsClient class.

Any ideas? Suggestions?

Comment: Is a logger really required by your Settings implementation?

Comment: Yes sure!
I have an idea to implement a separated class SettingsLogger:ILogger, which can be used only in SettingsClient and will collecting messages in memory, and when configuration completed and settings loaded I can move messages from the memory to the original Logger instance, and then replace SettingsLogger by Logger in SettingsClient class,
something like this. Does it look real?

Comment: Just asking. I didn't know if this was something you could orchestrate when the settings were consumed inside of your application logic. If logger is core to the implementation of settings then ignore my comment.

Comment: At first you need to change implementation of the classes. If you use DI, you don't need to instantiate classes inside each other. But now you create Producer inside Logger. Also you can extract one more class (ConnectionStringSettings) and use it as parameter in constructors.

Comment: ok, but how it can be done?
`class Logger:ILogger{Logger(IProducer producer)}`
...
`services.AddTransient<ISettingsClient,SettingsClient>();
services.AddSingleton<ILogger,Logger>(??);
services.AddSingleton<ISettings>(serviceProvider=>{var clientSettings=serviceProvider.GetService<ISettingsClient>(); return new Settings(clientSettings.GetSettings())});
services.AddTransient<IProducer,Producer>(??);`
it will not working  
We will get two recursive dependencies SettingsClient-Logger-Producer-SettingsClient 
Looks like it is not possible to implement it with using built-in DI contaner